# Vue Router produces a url with %2F for slug routes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

In my Vue 3 app, I need to add a route for dynamic slugs. I have added a route for it but `RouterLink` produces a url that includes `%2F` where a slash should be. I don't want that. I want my url to include actual slashes inside my slugs.

This is what I am getting now: `http://my.app/search/tool-based/1st-level%2F2nd-level%2F3rd-level`

But I would like it to be this: `http://my.app/search/tool-based/1st-level/2nd-level/3rd-level`

My slugs are unknown in size. It could be as short as `/category/another` or it could be `/category/another/another/another/another/another...` so I cannot hard-code this - it needs to be dynamic.

Here is my route:

```js
{
    path: '/search/tool-based/:slug(.*)',
    name: 'toolBasedSearch',
    component: () => import('@/views/tool-search/ToolBasedSearchView.vue'),
},
```

And here is my RouterLink (`category.canonicalUrl` comes from the database and it looks like `category1/category2/category3...`)

```
<template>
    <RouterLink
        v-for="category in categories"
        :to="{ name: 'toolBasedSearch', params: { slug: category.canonicalUrl } }"
        :key="category.uuid!">

        {{ category.namePlural }}
    </RouterLink>
</template>
```

Comment: did you try encodeURIComponent(YourURL) ?

var URL= "http://my.app/search/tool-based/" + encodeURIComponent(myUrl);

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found a solution myself. I needed to create the route like this instead:

```js
{
    path: '/search/tool-based/:slug+',
    name: 'toolBasedSearch',
    component: () => import('@/views/tool-search/ToolBasedSearchView.vue'),
},
```

and then pass an array to it like this by splitting my slug (creating an array):

```
<RouterLink
    v-for="category in categories"
    :to="{ name: 'toolBasedSearch', params: { slug: category.canonicalUrl.split('/') } }"
    :key="category.uuid!">

    {{ category.namePlural }}
</RouterLink>
```